# Is it best to have the OS on a separate virtual disk?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, raid1, raid10

I have a server with 8 drive bays, and I have eight 4TB drives.  Would it be best to do one RAID10 with all drives, or one RAID1 with two drives and then a RAID10 with the remaining six so that the operating system (Windows Server) has its own drive (and not just a partition)?

The large disk will house 1-3 VHDXs.
My priorities are first: redundancy, second: write speed, third: read speed.
Backups happen on a different machine.

Thank you for your time and feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This question is opinion based, but if it were me I'd create a RAID 1 array for the OS and a RAID 10 array for the virtual machines.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  Can I ask how you reached this opinion?  My thoughts are "If something goes wrong the second disk the first one is 'insulated' a bit."  Are yours along those same lines?